# Linearly reading a multi-dimensional array obeying dimensional sub-sectioning

Tags: algorithm, scala, multidimensional-array

I have an API for reading multi-dimensional arrays, requiring to pass a vector of ranges to read sub-rectangles (or hypercubes) from the backing array. I want to read this array "linearly", all elements in some given order with arbitrary chunk sizes. Thus, the task is with an `off` and a `len`, to translate the elements covered by this range into the smallest possible set of hyper-cubes, i.e. the smallest number of read commands issued in the API.

For example, we can calculate index vectors for the set of dimensions giving a linear index:

```
def calcIndices(off: Int, shape: Vector[Int]): Vector[Int] = {
  val modsDivs = shape zip shape.scanRight(1)(_ * _).tail
  modsDivs.map { case (mod, div) =>
    (off / div) % mod
  }
}
```

Let's say the shape is this, representing an array with rank 4 and 120 elements in total:

```
val sz  = Vector(2, 3, 4, 5)
val num = sz.product  // 120
```

A utility to print these index vectors for a range of linear offsets:

```
def printIndices(off: Int, len: Int): Unit =
  (off until (off + len)).map(calcIndices(_, sz))
    .map(_.mkString("[", ", ", "]")).foreach(println)
```

We can generate all those vectors:

```
printIndices(0, num)

[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 4]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 4]
[0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 2, 4]
[0, 0, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 3, 1]
[0, 0, 3, 2]
[0, 0, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
...
[1, 2, 1, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Let's look at an example chunk that should be read,
the first six elements:

```
val off1 = 0
val len1 = 6
printIndices(off1, len1)
```

I will already partition the output by hand into hypercubes:

```
// first hypercube or read
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 4]

// second hypercube or read
[0, 0, 1, 0]
```

**So the task is to define a method**

```
def partition(shape: Vector[Int], off: Int, len: Int): List[Vector[Range]]
```

which outputs the correct list and uses the smallest possible list size.
So for `off1` and `len1`, we have the expected result:

```
val res1 = List(
  Vector(0 to 0, 0 to 0, 0 to 0, 0 to 4),
  Vector(0 to 0, 0 to 0, 1 to 1, 0 to 0)
)

assert(res1.map(_.map(_.size).product).sum == len1)
```

A second example, elements at indices 6 until 22, with manual partitioning giving three hypercubes or read commands:

```
val off2 = 6
val len2 = 16
printIndices(off2, len2)

// first hypercube or read
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 4]

// second hypercube or read
[0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 2, 4]
[0, 0, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 3, 1]
[0, 0, 3, 2]
[0, 0, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 3, 4]

// third hypercube or read
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]

expected result:

val res2 = List(
  Vector(0 to 0, 0 to 0, 1 to 1, 1 to 4),
  Vector(0 to 0, 0 to 0, 2 to 3, 0 to 4),
  Vector(0 to 0, 1 to 1, 0 to 0, 0 to 1)
)

assert(res2.map(_.map(_.size).product).sum == len2)
```

Note that for `val off3 = 6; val len3 = 21`, we would need *four* readings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of the following algorithm is as follows:

- a point-of-interest (poi) is the left-most position
  at which two index representations differ
  (for example for `[0, 0, 0, 1]` and `[0, 1, 0, 0]` the poi is 1)
- we recursively sub-divide the original (start, stop) linear index range
- we use motions in two directions, first by keeping the start constant
  and decreasing the stop through a special "ceil" operation on the start,
  later by keeping the stop constant and increasing the start through
  a special "floor" operation on the stop
- for each sub range, we calculate the poi of the boundaries, and
  we calculate "trunc" which is ceil or floor operation described above
- if this trunc value is identical to its input, we add the entire region
  and return
- otherwise we recurse
- the special "ceil" operation takes the previous start value and
  increases the element at the poi index and zeroes the subsequent elements;
  e.g. for `[0, 0, 1, 1]` and `poi = 2`, the ceil would be `[0, 0, 2, 0]`
- the special "floor" operation takes the previous stop value and
  zeroes the elements after the poi index;
  e.g. for `[0, 0, 1, 1]`, and `poi = 2`, the floor would be `[0, 0, 1, 0]`

Here is my implementation. First, a few utility functions:

```
def calcIndices(off: Int, shape: Vector[Int]): Vector[Int] = {
  val modsDivs = (shape, shape.scanRight(1)(_ * _).tail, shape.indices).zipped
  modsDivs.map { case (mod, div, idx) =>
    val x = off / div
    if (idx == 0) x else x % mod
  }
}

def calcPOI(a: Vector[Int], b: Vector[Int], min: Int): Int = {
  val res = (a.drop(min) zip b.drop(min)).indexWhere { case (ai,bi) => ai != bi }
  if (res < 0) a.size else res + min
}

def zipToRange(a: Vector[Int], b: Vector[Int]): Vector[Range] =
  (a, b).zipped.map { (ai, bi) =>
    require (ai <= bi)
    ai to bi
  }

def calcOff(a: Vector[Int], shape: Vector[Int]): Int = {
  val divs = shape.scanRight(1)(_ * _).tail
  (a, divs).zipped.map(_ * _).sum
}

def indexTrunc(a: Vector[Int], poi: Int, inc: Boolean): Vector[Int] =
  a.zipWithIndex.map { case (ai, i) =>
    if      (i < poi) ai
    else if (i > poi) 0
    else if (inc)     ai + 1
    else              ai
  }
```

Then the actual algorithm:

```
def partition(shape: Vector[Int], off: Int, len: Int): List[Vector[Range]] = {
  val rankM = shape.size - 1

  def loop(start: Int, stop: Int, poiMin: Int, dir: Boolean,
           res0: List[Vector[Range]]): List[Vector[Range]] =
    if (start == stop) res0 else {
      val last = stop - 1
      val s0  = calcIndices(start, shape)
      val s1  = calcIndices(stop , shape)
      val s1m = calcIndices(last , shape)
      val poi = calcPOI(s0, s1m, poiMin)
      val ti  = if (dir) s0 else s1
      val to  = if (dir) s1 else s0
      val st  = if (poi >= rankM) to else indexTrunc(ti, poi, inc = dir)

      val trunc = calcOff(st, shape)
      val split = trunc != (if (dir) stop else start)

      if (split) {
        if (dir) {
          val res1 = loop(start, trunc, poiMin = poi+1, dir = true , res0 = res0)
          loop           (trunc, stop , poiMin = 0    , dir = false, res0 = res1)
        } else {
          val s1tm = calcIndices(trunc - 1, shape)
          val res1 = zipToRange(s0, s1tm) :: res0
          loop           (trunc, stop , poiMin = poi+1, dir = false, res0 = res1)
        }
      } else {
        zipToRange(s0, s1m) :: res0
      }
    }

  loop(off, off + len, poiMin = 0, dir = true, res0 = Nil).reverse
}
```

Examples:

```
val sz  = Vector(2, 3, 4, 5)
partition(sz, 0, 6)

// result:
List(
  Vector(0 to 0, 0 to 0, 0 to 0, 0 to 4),  // first  hypercube
  Vector(0 to 0, 0 to 0, 1 to 1, 0 to 0)   // second hypercube
)

partition(sz, 6, 21)

// result:
List(
  Vector(0 to 0, 0 to 0, 1 to 1, 1 to 4),  // first  read
  Vector(0 to 0, 0 to 0, 2 to 3, 0 to 4),  // second read
  Vector(0 to 0, 1 to 1, 0 to 0, 0 to 4),  // third  read
  Vector(0 to 0, 1 to 1, 1 to 1, 0 to 1)   // fourth read
)
```

The maximum number of reads, if I'm not mistaken, would be `2 * rank`.